# Reading Text File of Floats into a 2D Vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, fstream, ifstream

I have a data file comprised of thousands of float values and I want to read them into a 2D vector array and pass that vector to another routine once it's stored the floats from the file. When I run this code it prints out;

> [0][0] = 0, [0][1] = 0, etc.

The data file contains values like;

> 0.000579, 27.560021, etc.

```
int rows = 1000;
int cols = 2;
vector<vector<float>> dataVec(rows,vector<float>(cols));
ifstream in;
in.open("Data.txt");

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        in >> dataVec[i][j];    
        cout << "[ " << i << "][ " << j << "] = " << dataVec[i][j] << endl;
    }
}
in.close();
```

Comment: Does the file actually contain commas like you show, or is it purely whitespace-delimited? If it contains commas, then you need to extract those commas, too.

Comment: The reason for this might be that the values are too small for the default precision of `cout`. Add an include of `<iomanip>`, and change the output line as follows: `cout << "[ " << i << "][ " << j << "] = " << setprecision(10) << dataVec[i][j] << endl;`

Comment: No commas in the data file, just separated by whitespace. setprecision  didn't work but it was a great idea.

Comment: Simplify. Can you read one value? Can you read into a `vector<float>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me like the file could not be opened.  You did not test for success, so it will plough on regardless.  All your values were initialized to zero and will stay that way because every read fails.  This is conjecture, I admit, but I'd put money on it. =)

Comment: Yup, you're right. Although, I don't know why it's not opening.

Comment: Highly possible imo. Especially when you think you got the relative path of "Data.txt" right and assume the open file function will always work as such. Also usually in debug mode, uninitialized values are usually initialized to 0 for most IDE.

Comment: @OP: Put the full path of Data.txt instead of relative path and see if it works. E.g. "C:/Users/User/Documents/Data.txt" for example

Comment: Is the file locked by another process?  Is it a case-sensitive file system and you've got the case wrong?  If it's windows, did you escape the backslash character when you used the full path?  Have you tried reading the file in other programs, copying or deleting it?  Have you tried making a new test file and checking you can read it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, it works according to your specs:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

    ifstream infile;
    char cNum[10] ;
    int rows = 1;
    int cols = 2;
    vector<vector<float > > dataVec(rows,vector<float>(cols));

    infile.open ("test2.txt", ifstream::in);
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
            while (infile.good())
            {

                for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                    {

                        infile.getline(cNum, 256, ',');

                        dataVec[i][j]= atof(cNum) ;

                        cout <<dataVec[i][j]<<" , ";

                    }
                }



            }
            infile.close();
    }
    else
    {
            cout << "Error opening file";
    }

    cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();


   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void write(int m, int n)
{
    ofstream ofs("data.txt");
    if (!ofs) {
        cerr << "write error" << endl;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            ofs << i+j << " ";
}

void read(int m, int n)
{
    ifstream ifs("data.txt");
    if (!ifs) {
        cerr << "read error" << endl;
        return;
    }

    vector<float> v;
    float a;
    while (ifs >> a) v.push_back(a);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << "[" << i << "][" << j << "] = "
                 << v[i*n+j] << ", ";
}

int main()
{
    write(2,2);
    read(2,2);

    return 0;
}
```